# API кинотеатров в мобильном приложении

Tags: api, мобильные-приложения

Ребят, как подключить в мобильное приложение бронирование билетов в кино? Писал яндекс (у них яндекс афиша), перенаправили на свой источник, там не отвечают, возможно от того, что принимают заявки лишь от кинотеатров. Писал рамблер-кассы, молчат. Связался с киноход, там сказали что мне напишет их специалист, но этого чудо не произошло. Кто-нибудь сталкивался с бронированием? Было бы круто уже не бронирование, а хотя бы цены узнать на сеанс. (API под кинотеатры городов России я нашел, но там нет цен на сеансы).

Comment: Не смотрели? https://toster.ru/q/196795 Ничего нового вроде, вы и так с киноходом уже общаетесь. Но может будет полезное что-то...

Comment: Спасибо что отреагировали на мой вопрос. Смотрел, из этого поста нашел Киноход. Когда с ними общался (ответили через часа 2), просили показать сайт, но сайта нет, делаю моб. приложение. Сказали что мне напишет их специалист. Было около четырех дней назад Может быть конечно мне и ответят через недельку, но я не думаю

Comment: проблема в том, что, скорее всего, у всех провайдеров нужных вам данных уже есть свое мобильное приложение. Конкурент им не нужен. Я думаю, единственный способ - какое-то лютое приложение с бешеной популярностью, к которому вы зачем-то можете нужный вам функционал захотеть прикрутить - тогда они, конечно, сразу все ответят

Comment: Может, как вариант реализовать на хостинге парсер (или же кинотеатры будут предоставлять вам необходимую информацию в удобочитаемом виде) интересующей информации (производить обход сайтов кинозалов и сохранять у себя необходимую информацию) и уже с помощью мобильного приложения предоставлять к ней доступ пользователям.

Comment: Парсинг таких сайтов, разве законно?

Comment: @ed8009 парсинг чего угодно, — всегда законно. Вы берете информацию из открытых источников. Но если будете делать это с одного и того-же IP, вас вероятно, забанять по IP, например, на тысячном запросе. А может и не забанят. Но противозаконного в этом ничего нет.

Comment: + Я думаю, вам стоит подождать, а через  неделю их еще раз пингануть. Ну и если не будет результата, пинговать их с некоторым таймаутом. В подобных конторах реагируют медленно не из-за вредности, а из-за безумной загруженности сотрудников. Пинговать не будете — про вас очень быстро забудут, даже если изначально были заинтереснованы.